# Emulating the Facebook iOS App login, Special user-agent being sent?

Tags: php

Basically I'm trying to emulate the process that the Facebook official iphone app uses to log into Facebook.
it seems that it may be sending a special header/user-agent to identify itself so after logging in Facebook doesn't require it to name the "new device", instead it's automatically recognized as Facebook for iPhone.

is anybody aware of the headers being sent or the method being used to do that?

Comment: Inspect the request with Wireshark or something. That would show you the headers being sent.

Comment: In addition to @phindmarsh's idea of Wireshark you may need to disable SSL

Answer (score 0):

That's not a header. The iPhone app is able to read the iPhone/iPod/iPad device serial number from iOS and it sends that information along with the request. It's not a user agent header, but the ID of the device itself as each apple hardware product has its own unique serial number. That is what allows you to "remember a device" with a lot of social apps.

But if you want to see exactly how the facebook app is sending the data, the commenters are correct. You would need to install wireshark (or another packet sniffer tool) on a computer on your network, disable SSL on the facebook app (which I don't think you can even do anymore) and then monitor the traffic from the app to see the request packets and their data.

I think a more important question is why do you want to emulate that? Facebook provides a full API you can use in mobile apps, web apps, desktop apps, etc to connect/login/post/etc for users' accounts. Why not just use that API? It's well documented: http://developers.facebook.com/